# Laravel Eloquent - Retrieve data from relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, model

I need help being able to get data from the relationship between users, roles and permissions in my database. Please see below...

Database:

users

```
id    name   role_id
1     Phil   1
2     Rob    1
3     Dave   2
```

user_roles

```
id    name
1     Admin
2     Staff
```

permissions

```
id    endpoint
1     /users
2     /roles
```

user_role_permissions

```
user_role_id     permissions_id
1                1
1                2
1                2
```

From the user model I would like to be able to get the data from the permissions table, so I know what access the user has.

Here's the models:

User.php

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract
{
use Authenticatable, Authorizable, SoftDeletes;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'role_id'
];

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password',
];

protected $dates = [
    'deleted_at'
];

public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public permissions()
{
    ?????
}

}
```

UserRole.php

```
class UserRole extends Model {

protected $fillable = ['name'];

protected $hidden = [];

public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}

public function permissions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Permission', 'user_role_permissions');
}

}
```

Permission.php

```
class Permission extends Model {

protected $fillable = ['endpoint'];

protected $hidden = [];

public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\UserRoles','user_role_permissions');
}

}
```

Please help!

Comment: You've a typo in `User` model `role()`. It should be `App\UserRole`.

Comment: Thank you Zeshan for pointing out my typo 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've correctly defined all the required relationships. You can use it like:

```php
User::with('role.permissions')->first();
// It gives you all the permissions that are assigned to the role assigned to the underlying user :)
// Pretty vague to explain though
```

You don't need to define `permission()` on `User` model.